# Open windows explorer at a specific network location in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, explorer

I have tried so many variants of a theme to get this explorer window open at the P:\ drive, from what my little knowledge tells me, the fact the path to the folder is anywhere but the C:\ drive means it fails (it works with C:) so perhaps the path is wrong? the code below shows some of the tries i have made but still no luck, "P:" is mapped the same on all machines.

```
def Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Dir():
    import subprocess
    fldrname = os.path.basename(currentproject.get())
    print(fldrname)
    #subprocess.Popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE', cwd=(P:/Projects 2013/)
    #subbprocess.Popen('c:\\windows\\EXPLORER.EXE' cwd=('P:\\Projects_2013\\')fldrname)
    #subprocess.Popen(r'C:/Windows/explorer.exe', cwd=r'//WRDBSVR/Project_Data/Projects_2013/'+fldrname)
    subprocess.Popen('explorer /n, /select r"\\192.168.0.27\\Project_Data\\Projects_2013\\"'+fldrname)
    #subprocess.Popen('explorer /n, /select r"P:\\Project_Data\\Projects_2013\\"'+fldrname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appart from the fact that Ashish Nitin Patil's answer is definitly better, as using a variable for paths is always a good idea, you have a problem with your quotes:

```
# This line is not correct
'explorer /n, /select r"\\192.168.0.27\\Project_Data\\Projects_2013\\"'+fldrname
#                      ^you start a new string without ending previous one
# this one is correct
'explorer /n, /select ' + r'\192.168.0.27\Project_Data\Projects_2013\' + fldrname
#                     ^first ending string start
```

Besides, using raw strings (`r"xxx"`) means that `\` will not escape characters, so you shall not double them. If you want to double them, you do not need prepend `r`.

Last remark: take care to avoid string concatenation (`+`) when working with paths; you should use `os.path.join()` instead.

Comment: Joel - yes by using @ashish original idea and your idea for os.join i created this:  'newdir = os.path.join("P:\\Projects_2013", fldrname)
        subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format(newdir))' and it works, cant thank you guys enough, time to let my hair grow back.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format(full_folder_path))` works, but how do I get this window on top of other windows, if the user goes to some other window after having executed this statement somewhere in his program?

Comment: I don't know how I could do that, but anyway, are you sure you want to do that? I'm always irritated when the system pops a window when I just selected other one :-/

Comment: Hahaha. Yes its irritating, but for my application, I kinda require that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

well to open My pc (for windows) try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('explorer ""')

"#if subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}".format(full_path)') is struck at pc\my documents.
where full_path=os.path.join("your/path")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the job.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format(full_folder_path))
```

Update -

Tested on my system -

```
full_path = os.path.join("P:/Project_Data/Projects_2013/",fldrname)
print full_path # Verify that it is correct
subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format(full_path))
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work, it opens explorer at the 'C:\my documents' folder which is its default: 'subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format("P:/Project_Data/Projects_2013/"+fldrname))' and 'subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format("\\wrdbsvr\\Project_Data\\Projects_2013\\"+fldrname)) both do the same

Comment: Maybe either the `/n, /select` options of `explorer` command are missing in the command-line, or forward-slashes `/` are not accepted by `explorer`?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen('explorer "{0}"'.format(full_folder_path))` works, but how do I get this window on top of other windows, if say the user goes to some other window after having executed this statement somewhere in his program?